# Integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{r^2\log(r^2 - 1)}{(r^2 - 1)^2} \, dr$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

How do I calculate:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{r^2 \log(r^2 - 1)}{(r^2 - 1)^2} \, dr$$

Basically, I have been attempting this integration for a while using multiple methods so any hints or suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: have you shown that this integral does converge on the given interval?

Comment: How are you defining $\log(r^2-1)$ for $0\lt r\lt1$?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not locally integrable at $(0,+\infty) $.
it should be $\int_1... $.

if it is the case, use by parts integration to transform $\ln $ to a fraction.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{r^2 \log(r^2 - 1)}{(r^2 - 1)^2} dr$$
take $\log(r^2 - 1)$ =$t$ then 
$(r^2 - 1)$=$e^t$ and $r^2=e^t+1$
also 
$\frac{2r}{(r^2-1)}dr$=$dt$

Now, $$\int \frac{\sqrt(e^t+1)t}{2e^t} dt$$
can you carry on from here?

Comment: But then the lower $r$ limit is $0$, which implies $\sqrt{e^t+1}=0\implies e^t=-1\implies t=$???

Comment: @JohnDoe one can simply integrate this letting $t$ and then replace it with $log(r^2-1)$ after integration and then taken limit from infinity and 0.

Comment: I feel like this would lead to the limit not existing. Also wolfram alpha doesn't give a particularly nice form for the integral you have transformed into. Also as pointed out in the comments, this integral doesn't converge

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of headaches involved with this integral. The worst is that for $r<1$ the integrand has an imaginary   part which is $\pm i\pi$ depending on choiice of ranch for the log, and the integral from $0$ to $1$ of the imaginary part looks like 
i\pi$\int_1^\infty (1-s^2)^-2ds$(after sustituting $r=1/s$, and this does not converge.

the other headache is that neither of the real part integrals converge, and even the sum of the integrand obtained from the substitution with the original integrand (which is tempting because the limits of integration will both be $1$ to $\infty$ does not converge.

Are you sure you have the problem right?